# Add a Permalink To a Post Title?

Tags: taxonomy

I'm remaking a Real Estate website for the company i work for using Wordpress along with houzez theme and elementor, The theme is using posts as properties where you can select all the property features, property types... using post_type=property,

I'm trying to make it so that the title of each property is dynamic displaying the [property type]-[state]-[area] [city] displayed in that order. (image for reference)

i need it that way because the website will have multiple languages and that's how the current website displays the info, i'm currently mocking the information by manually typing "apartment" - "state-name" - "area name" etc... in the post title, is it even possible? what workaround can i try? any help is appreciated!

[image: how it should look]

[image: how i tried but didnt work unsurprisingly]

[image: Taxonomies]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can output custom fields on the front end. You'll need to start by creating a child theme. You can then copy whichever file applies - the one you're showing looks like perhaps an `archive.php`, `category.php`, or something similar. Finally, tweak the output so that in addition to (or instead of) the title you're outputting the particular fields in the order you wish.

The complicating factors here are that you're using a paid theme as well as a page builder. The page builder may significantly complicate figuring out how to output everything. If you just use the real estate theme and create a child theme, and use plugins for anything else you need, you'll likely have an easier time outputting the custom fields and adjusting the theme.